# "Server doesn't listen" error connecting to my remote database

Tags: postgresql, nginx

I have a Postgres database on a remote server. I fill out this info in pgAdmin.

```
Name: my-server
Host: SERVER.IP.ADDRESS.HERE
Port: 5432
Maintenance DB: postgres
Username: django
password: mysecretpassword
```

When I hit "OK" I get this error window.

```
Server doesn't listen

The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "SERVER.IP.ADDRESS.HERE" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

How do I check what port Postgres runs on in my remote server, which runs Ubuntu 14.04? Why do I get this error?

**Update**

Ran `SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'port';`. Port is definitely 5432.

Ran `nano /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf`. Uncommented `listen_addresses` so it looks like this:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost','*'
```

Ran `nginx restart`, tried connecting again. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart` got rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the port like so: `SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'port';`

Comment: Updated question